# Count keywords from a string

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the keywords in a string from a webpage:

```
#get the URL
u <- "http://www.dlink.com/it/it" 
doc <- getURL(u)

#get the text from the body
html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE)
txt <- xpathApply(html, "//body//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)]", xmlValue)
txt<-toString(txt)
txt

#clean
str_replace_all(txt, "[\r\n\t,]" , "")

search <- c("Wi-Fi","Router","Switch","ADSL")
search
stri_detect_fixed(txt, search)

sum(stri_detect_fixed(text, search))
```

Unfortunately counts only if the word is in or not, instead, I want to count how many keywords are present (e.g if Wi-Fi is present two times would be +2), any idea using the stringi library?

Comment: Maybe  `stri_count_fixed(txt, search)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stri_count_fixed`

```
library(stringi)

stri_count_fixed(txt, search)
[1] 3 2 5 1

sum(stri_count_fixed(txt, search))
[1] 11
```